# Gnome: apps extend under dock after suspension

Tags: gnome, dock

In Ubuntu 22.04 I have dock configured to be on the bottom part of the screen. When computer enters suspension mode and I login back, some running windows extends to the bottom of the screen and are partly hidden under the dock instead of extending only to the edge of the dock, which is normal and desired function.

I think this also happens when the dock is on the left but in the tests I just did now it didn't happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you figure out how to solve it in the meantime ? Thanx